# SQL: Add Column from table to another

Tags: sql, union

I have two tables that count records and displays the count by month.

I want to show both counts on the same table, but I'm not sure how to combine them.

[image]

[image]

I just want to add the "IM Count" column to the first table, to the right of "CR Count."

Below is the code for the first table.  The second table is similar code, but it draws its data from another table.  My main issue is that I don't have a column that matches between tables.  (The Year and Month columns technically do match, but only because they are both counts per month.)

```
Use sm

select 
year(planned_start) Year, 

Case
    When month(planned_start) = 1 then 'January'
    When month(planned_start) = 2 then 'February'
    When month(planned_start) = 3 then 'March'
    When month(planned_start) = 4 then 'April'
    When month(planned_start) = 5 then 'May'
    When month(planned_start) = 6 then 'June'
    When month(planned_start) = 7 then 'July'
    When month(planned_start) = 8 then 'August'
    When month(planned_start) = 9 then 'September'
    When month(planned_start) = 10 then 'October'
    When month(planned_start) = 11 then 'November'
    When month(planned_start) = 12 then 'December'
end as Month,
count(*) 'CR Count'

from dbo.cm3rm1
where planned_start between dateadd(Year,-1,getdate()) and getdate()
and
    category !='OAS Normal'
group by year(planned_start), month(planned_start)
order by year(planned_start), month(planned_start)
```

Comment: well, if you have the year and the month on the side, you can do a join. But do a join after having grouped the data else you will have duplicated data

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, though.  I need some kind of temporary table, don't I?  Also, when using a JOIN, I need to say which columns match, but in my case, I need to match two columns, Year and Month.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Your query is invalid standard SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the "idea" :

```
SELECT tmp_CR.Year, 
Case 
 When tmp_CR.month = 1 then 'January'
 When tmp_CR.month = 2 then 'February'
 When tmp_CR.month = 3 then 'March'
 When tmp_CR.month = 4 then 'April'
 When tmp_CR.month = 5 then 'May'
 When tmp_CR.month = 6 then 'June'
 When tmp_CR.month = 7 then 'July'
 When tmp_CR.month = 8 then 'August' 
 When tmp_CR.month = 9 then 'September'
 When tmp_CR.month = 10 then 'October'
 When tmp_CR.month = 11 then 'November'
 When tmp_CR.month = 12 then 'December' end as month, 
 tmp_CR.CR_Count, 
 tmp_IM.IM_Count
FROM (
 select 
  year(planned_start) Year, 
  month(planned_start) as Month,
  count(*) as CR_Count
 from dbo.TABLE_1
 where planned_start between dateadd(Year,-1,getdate()) and getdate()
   and
    category !='OAS Normal'
 group by year(planned_start), month(planned_start) 
) tmp_CR
INNER JOIN (
 select 
  year(planned_start) Year, 
  month(planned_start) as Month, as Month,
  count(*) as IM_Count
 from dbo.TABLE_2
 where planned_start between dateadd(Year,-1,getdate()) and getdate()
   and
    category !='OAS Normal'
 group by year(planned_start), month(planned_start) 
) tmp_IM ON tmp_CR.year = tmp_IM.year and tmp_CR.month = tmp_IM.month
ORDER BY tmp_CR.Year, tmp_CR.month
```

Comment: If you want more visibility, create two view, and do simple select ..from .. join ..

Comment: Oh this is perfect, and worked great.  Thanks so much!

Comment: One problem now.  Since the ORDER BY command is after the JOIN, it sorts the Months alphabetically, instead of by number.

Comment: ok it wasn't smart from me. Just use month(planned_start) in the two subquery, then do the case / when stuff in the top select .

Comment: Hrm.  I think I understand, but when I try to do that, I get the error that "January" can't be converted to data type int.

Comment: i eddited my answer

Comment: Perfect.  It seems to be working exactly right now.  I'll admit, I don't really understand why it works.

Comment: Sorry to keep going, but with this new method, how does it sort by Month correctly?  I see at the end, the ORDER BY tmp_CR.month, but isn't tmp_CR.month already set to strings?  (January, february, etc.)  How is it sorting the month numerically?

Comment: tmp_CR.month is the result of the subquery, so it's set to month(planned_start). Use different alias in the select of the subquery if you want thing to be more clear